# Apache Jmeter 4.0 Java IO Error Resultcollector

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am getting below error while replaying the script.

```
ERROR o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Exception occurred while initializing file output.
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.getFileWriter(ResultCollector.java:449) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.testStarted(ResultCollector.java:324) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.testStarted(ResultCollector.java:350) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:215) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:384) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_66]
```

Though it is not impacting the replay. Need to understand the reason and fixes for the same. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome! We probably will need enough of the script so the error can be generated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to avoid using non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters and spaces in

   - java installation
   - JMeter installation
   - test script location
   - results file location(s)

     as you might be suffering from something like [JDK-4904545 : JDK tools fail to work with non-latin characters in the install path](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4904545)
2. According to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) you should stick to latest JMeter version so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or to the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page). It won't fix particular your issue, however theoretically JMeter should become faster and have some new features